# How do I add more background colors for confluence tables pallette?

Tags: confluence

When colouring the tables in confluence i feel a bit limited by the 6 available colours on the tables, I want to know if its possible to add aditional colours to the pallette through the adminstration functions. Also is it possible to alter the existing colours.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's no good way to do this, see the [bug report](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFSERVER-27618).

Nevertheless, there seems to exist a [hack](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFSERVER-6482?focusedCommentId=779746&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-779746)